# Rust: future factory method results in compiler error: value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-futures

I want to repeat a certain user-provided function multiple times in an async context. Thus, I thought about a non-async closure that produces futures which can be consumed/awaited.

A minimal reproducible example is the following:

```rust
let counter = Arc::new(AtomicU64::new(0));
let counter_closure = counter.clone();
let future_producer = move || async {
    counter_closure.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
};
```

but this results in this error

```
562 |           let future_producer = move || async {
    |  _______________________________-------_^
    | |                               |     |
    | |                               |     return type of closure `impl Future<Output = ()>` contains a lifetime `'2`
    | |                               lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
563 | |             counter_closure.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
564 | |         };
    | |_________^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the closure owns `counter_closure` but the futures returned by the closure only *reference* this value owned by the closure.  The signature of closures doesn't have a way to express this.  It's akin to the "owning iterator" problem -- like how the `Iterator` trait doesn't permit expression of the case where the iterator dispenses references tied to its own lifetime, the family of closure traits that can be invoked on a reference to a closure (`Fn` and `FnMut`) don't have a way to express that the value returned from the closure borrows from the closure itself.

If the compiler permitted this to compile, it would be possible to create a use-after-free situation by dropping the closure while futures it has previously returned still exist.  This would destroy `counter_closure` while it's still borrowed.

You can fix this by cloning the closure-owned `counter_closure` on each invocation of the closure *before* the `async` block, and moving this clone into the future with `async move`:

```
let counter = Arc::new(AtomicU64::new(0));
let counter_closure = counter.clone();
let future_producer = move || {
    let counter_inner = counter_closure.clone();
    async move {
        counter_inner.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
};
```

This uncouples the lifetime of the future from the closure by giving the future its own `Arc`.

Comment: @phip1611 No problem. It's a pretty weird situation and the compiler output, while accurate, tells you _what_ is wrong without going into much detail about _why it can't work,_ which means that the solution isn't necessarily immediately obvious unless you already understand how closures and async blocks interact.